# Linq query for Where on the Joined table without needing join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, join

Trying to get a linq query (or lambda syntax) for the following SQL which Selects all "Data" which in the joining table have an Attribute equal to "blob".

EXCEPT: without explictly using the Join, but the

```
select data.*
from data
    join settings on data.DataID = settings.DataID
where settings.Attribute = 'blob'
```

Explicitly defining the join

```
from d in dbcontext.Data
  join s in dbcontext.Settings on d.DataID equals s.DataID
where s.Attribute == "blob"
select d
```

but is there a way to use the context  dbcontext.Data.Settings
like the following?

```
from d in dbcontext.Data
where d.Settings.Attribute == "blob"
select d
```

Settings is a collection Type, so things like  .Contains, and .Where come to mind.

using .Contains, my understanding is i would need to pass in an object type

```
where d.Settings.Contains(new Settings(d.DataID, "blob", null))
```

but i dont care about the null (Value) matching, just column Settings

some table structures

```
Data
   DataID
   Name

Settings
    DataID
    Attribute
    Value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand, you have `Settings` collection navigation property, so instead of explicit join you could simply use it ("navigate"):

```
from d in dbcontext.Data
from s in d.Settings
where s.Attribute == "blob"
select d
```

Alternatively you could use [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method which in this case is more appropriate than `Contains` (although `Contains` can also be used, but needs to be combined with `Select`):

```
dbcontext.Data.Where(d => d.Settings.Any(s => s.Attribute == "blob"))
```

For completeness, here is the `Contains` version:

```
dbcontext.Data.Where(d => d.Settings.Select(s => s.Attribute).Contains("blob"))
```

Comment: Great. To note 2 points. trace of using this from s in d.Settings creates the SQL I mentioned. But LinqPad which for curiosity more then anything, creates a From Data, Settings WHERE data.Id = Settings.ID sql, which been a long time since I have seen join done that way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to create a LINQ that will grab any DataID that has an attribute of of "Blah" that is stored in another table.

If so this may work.

```
var dataIDs = Setting.Where(entry => entry.Attribute == "Blah")
             .Select(entry => entry.DataID); // gets all DataIDs that match the attribute

var data = Data.Where(entry => entry.DataID in dataIDs); // gets data info based on DataIDs.
```

It should work, but what you should do instead is do an left join somewhat like

```
select a.*
from data a
    left join settings b
on a.DataID = b.DataID
where b.Attribute = 'blob'
```

but in LINQ.  This query would allow you to fetch all the data for DataIDs that match attribute 'blob.  I haven't done it in LINQ so if someone more familiar with left joins with linq could respond that might work better